why the font size still different even i standardize the font already
enter image description here
enter image description here
I'm facing challenges in achieving consistent font sizes for the search bar and create button on my web pages. Despite standardizing the font size in my CSS, the search bar appears longer than expected, and the create button's font size seems larger on one page compared to another. Could you guys please provide guidance on how to ensure uniform font sizes for these elements?
here is the css code:


/* Common styles for both home and trending pages */
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Roboto', Arial, sans-serif; /* Standardize font family */
  font-size: 16px; /* Standardize base font size */
  display: flex;
}

.vertical-menu {
  width: 240px;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 2px 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  overflow-y: auto;
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
  height: 100vh;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.vertical-menu .menu-header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 16px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.vertical-menu .logo {
  max-width: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.vertical-menu a {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #333;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
}

.vertical-menu a i {
  margin-right: 12px;
}

.vertical-menu a:hover {
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
}

.vertical-menu a.active {
  background-color: #0079d3;
  color: white;
}

.top-bar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  padding: 16px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  background-color: #f6f6f6;
  width: 100%; /* Adjusted to full width */
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.search-bar {
  background-image: url(image/search.png);
  background-size: 20px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: right;
  width: 100%; /* Adjusted to full width */
  max-width: 600px;
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 20px; /* Rounded corners */
  font-family: 'Roboto', Arial, sans-serif; /* Ensure consistent font family */
  font-size: 16px; /* Adjust font size */
}

.profile-icon {
  font-size: 20px; /* Adjusted font size */
  margin-right: 25px;
  padding: 8px; /* Padding inside the border */
  display: inline-block; /* Ensures it behaves as a block element */
  text-decoration: none; /* Removes default underline */
  color: #333; /* Text color */
}

.create-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
  margin-right: 16px; /* Adjusted margin */
}

.create {
  width: 24px; /* Adjusted icon size */
  height: 24px; /* Adjusted icon size */
  margin-right: 8px;
}

.content {
  margin-left: 240px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  padding: 16px;
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-align: left;
}

.forum-discussion {
  overflow: hidden; /* Hide overflow content */
  text-overflow: ellipsis; /* Truncate text */
  white-space: nowrap; /* Prevent wrapping */
  max-width: 1190px;
  max-height: 240px;
  margin-top: 2%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.subforum-avatar {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.subforum-date {
  color: #888;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.description h1 {
  font-size: 18px;
  margin: 0;
}

.subforum-description p {
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.subforum-description ul {
  list-style-type: disc;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.gold,
.silver,
.bronze {
  float:right;
  width: 70px;
}

.forum-discussion-link {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  display: block;
}

.forum-discussion {
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 8px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

/* Hover effect */
.forum-discussion-link:hover .forum-discussion {
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  transform: translateY(-2px);
}

/* Active/focus effect */
.forum-discussion-link:focus .forum-discussion,
.forum-discussion-link:active .forum-discussion {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transform: translateY(-4px);
}

/* Additional effects */
.forum-discussion-link .forum-discussion {
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease, box-shadow 0.3s ease, transform 0.3s ease;
}

.forum-discussion .subforum-avatar i {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.forum-discussion h1 {
  margin: 10px 0;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.forum-discussion p,
.forum-discussion ul {
  margin: 10px 0;
}

.forum-discussion ul {
  list-style-type: disc;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta3/css/all.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;500;700&display=swap">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="home.css">
    <title>Trending</title>
    <style>
        .medal {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 30px; /* Adjust size as needed */
            height: auto;
            margin-right: 5px;
        }

        .content{
          margin-left: 240px;
        }
        .filter{
          margin-left: -15px;
        }


    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="vertical-menu">
        <div class="menu-header">
            <a href="home.php">
                <img src="image/project logo.png" alt="Logo" class="logo">
            </a>
        </div>
        <a href="home.php"><i class="fas fa-home"></i> Home</a>
        <a href="trending.php?filter=all" <?php if ($filter == 'all') echo 'class="active"'; ?><i class="fas fa-chart-line"></i> Trending</a>
        <a href="about.php"><i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i> About</a>
    </div>
    <div class="top-bar">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search Discussion" class="search-bar">
        <a href="create.html" class="create-container">
            <img src="image/edit.png" alt="create" class="create">
            <span>Create</span>
        </a>
        <a href="login page.html" class="fas fa-user profile-icon"></a> <!-- Icon with user's name -->
    </div>




The most useful tool for debugging issues like this is the Inspector in your web browser. You can inspect any element on your page and see which style rules are being applied to it, the order they are applied, and the source code location of each rule. Find an introductory tutorial for the inspector of your favourite browser and read it.

I have seen some problems in your CSS, some may be related to your issue.

W3.css defines your body font-size (which is inherited to all childs) as 15px where you explicitly put it to 16px in your code. Have a look on css specificity to fix this issue.

Your body misses a closing tag (</body>)

Be aware that users using a custom font size inside their browser config will see their settings overwritten by your css. Using rem/em may help you "standardize" your font-size and improve accessibility

Your W3c.css add a text-size-adjust property which may infer with your font-size if you check with responsive settings.


As Brett suggested, use the Inspector on your webpage to see which font-size is used, and where it is comming from.

we can see that your font size is 15px, which comes from by the rule html, body defined in w3.css line 27.

You can also check in the "computed" section, if you hover on the property and click on the arrow, where the property is coming from
(The inspector part is from Chrome, but all browsers nowadays have those kind of feature)
